# Question in Snowflake Pro Cetitifcation assesssment

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-webui

Can someone know the right answer for this question encountered during one of my mock exam --

Which SQL statements will not work in the Web UI?

1)CREATE INDEX and DROP INDEX

2)CREATE USER, ALTER USER, DROP USER

3)CREATE TABLESPACE, ALTER TABLESPACE and DROP TABLESPACE

4. CREATE LOGFILE GROUP, ALTER LOGFILE GROUP and DROP LOGFILE GROUP
5. CREATE SERVER, ALTER SERVER and DROP SERVER
6. CREATE WAREHOUSE, ALTER WAREHOUSE, DROP WAREHOUSE

I marked 4 and 5 but got wrong .

Comment: I would go with CREATE TABLESPACE, ALTER TABLESPACE and DROP TABLESPACE because they seem like alias functionality statements, not need to have functionality. That being said, I am no expert on the system you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

In the WebUI, it won't work:

1. CREATE INDEX and DROP INDEX

> There is no direct index in Snowflake, you can manage clustering and
> enable Search Optimization.

3. CREATE TABLESPACE, ALTER TABLESPACE and DROP TABLESPACE

> There is no such thing in Snowflake, we don't need to create space for
> tables.

4. CREATE LOGFILE GROUP, ALTER LOGFILE GROUP and DROP LOGFILE GROUP

> Snowflake to SaaS, we do not manage data or log files.

5. CREATE SERVER, ALTER SERVER and DROP SERVER

> There is no such feature in Snowfalke.

The following possibilities can be performed:

2. CREATE USER, ALTER USER, DROP USER
3. CREATE WAREHOUSE, ALTER WAREHOUSE, DROP WAREHOUSE

You can find your quiz questions here:
[SnowPro Certification - On Demand Knowledge Check Questions](https://quizlet.com/580777973/snowpro-certification-on-demand-knowledge-check-questions-flash-cards/)

If you click on the question itself, you will see the correct answers.